# How to preserve case of characters when using Caesar Cipher

Tags: ruby, caesar-cipher

I have a Caesar Cipher script in Ruby that is working but it returns the string as all upper-case letters instead of preserving the cases of the original string.

I could use `capitalize` to make it look good enough but I would like a more concrete way of preserving the cases.

Here is the script:

```
BASE_ORD = 'A'.ord

def caesar_cipher(phrase, key)
  cipher = phrase.gsub(/[a-z]/i) do |c|
    orig_pos = c.upcase.ord - BASE_ORD
    new_pos = (orig_pos + key) % 26
    (new_pos + BASE_ORD).chr
  end
  puts cipher
end

caesar_cipher("What a string!", 5)
```

Any help or insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Your regex is case-insensitive, you probably want to capture all actual cases: `phrase.gsub(/\w/)`

Comment: @Brennan: `\w` also includes some things that are not letters, so `[a-zA-Z]` would be better. The problem is actually `upcase`. And in any case, this is easier to do with `tr` than with `gsub`.

Comment: Ruby has an easier way than UTF-8/Unicode... [Here's the github link to mine.](https://github.com/c650/Caesar_Cipher)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution, given your existing code, is to check whether the character is uppercase or lowercase and set `base_ord` accordingly. Since the lowercase letters come after the uppercase letters in UTF-8 (as in ASCII), we can just test `letter >= 'a'`, e.g.:

```
base_ord = (letter >= 'a' ? 'a' : 'A').ord
```

Here's the whole method with this change (you no longer need the `BASE_ORD` constant):

```
def caesar_cipher(phrase, key)
  phrase.gsub(/[a-z]/i) do |letter|
    base_ord = (letter >= 'a' ? 'a' : 'A').ord
    orig_pos = letter.ord - base_ord
    new_pos = (orig_pos + key) % 26
    (new_pos + base_ord).chr
  end
end

puts caesar_cipher("What a string!", 5) # => Bmfy f xywnsl!
```

#### Edit

Amadan makes a good point about using [`String#tr`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/String.html#method-i-tr). Here's a somewhat more concise implementation:

```
ALPHABET = "aAbBcCdDeEfFgGhHiIjJkKlLmMnNoOpPqQrRsStTuUvVwWxXyYzZ"
# Or if you want to be fancy: ALPHABET = (?a..?z).flat_map {|c| [ c, c.upcase ] }.join

def caesar_cipher(phrase, key)
  to_alphabet = ALPHABET.dup
  to_alphabet << to_alphabet.slice!(0, key * 2)
  phrase.tr(ALPHABET, to_alphabet)
end

puts caesar_cipher("What a string!", 5) # => Bmfy f xywnsl!
```

Comment: Thanks! using the greater than or equal sign worked great! I'll have to try the String#tr method though, that looks a little simpler!

Answer (score 1):

As said in comments, `tr` is easier to use for Caesar Cypher (once you prepare the two alphabets), and should also be much faster:

```
class CaesarCypher
    def initialize(key, alphabet=nil)
        @from_alphabet = alphabet || (?a..?z).to_a.join
        @to_alphabet = @from_alphabet[key..-1] + @from_alphabet[0...key]
        @from_alphabet += @from_alphabet.upcase
        @to_alphabet += @to_alphabet.upcase
    end
    def encode(str)
        str.tr(@from_alphabet, @to_alphabet)
    end
    def encode!(str)
        str.tr!(@from_alphabet, @to_alphabet)
    end
    def decode(str)
        str.tr(@to_alphabet, @from_alphabet)
    end
    def decode(str)
        str.tr!(@to_alphabet, @from_alphabet)
    end
end

cc = CaesarCypher.new(1)
puts cc.encode("Caesar, huh?")
puts cc.decode("Dbftbs, ivi?")
```