# Assistance needed with my encryption program

Tags: java, encryption

I created an encryption program using the method input.replace as it is supposed to encrypt a user's input but an issue I have been having is that the code never fully encrypts. For example, if I were to input the word "happy" the word outputs "haccl", leaving the 'h' and the 'a' untouched when they should be encrypted as well. Here is my code:

```
public class HelloWorld
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.print("Input a word: ");
        Scanner inputscan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = inputscan.nextLine();

        input = input.replace('A', 'N');
        input = input.replace('B', 'O');
        input = input.replace('C', 'P');
        input = input.replace('D', 'Q');
        input = input.replace('E', 'R');
        input = input.replace('F', 'S');
        input = input.replace('G', 'T');
        input = input.replace('H', 'U');
        input = input.replace('I', 'V');
        input = input.replace('J', 'W');
        input = input.replace('K', 'X');
        input = input.replace('L', 'Y');
        input = input.replace('M', 'Z');
        input = input.replace('N', 'A');
        input = input.replace('O', 'B');
        input = input.replace('P', 'C');
        input = input.replace('Q', 'D');
        input = input.replace('R', 'E');
        input = input.replace('S', 'F');
        input = input.replace('T', 'G');
        input = input.replace('U', 'H');
        input = input.replace('V', 'I');
        input = input.replace('W', 'J');
        input = input.replace('X', 'K');
        input = input.replace('Y', 'L');
        input = input.replace('Z', 'M');
        input = input.replace('a', 'n');
        input = input.replace('b', 'o');
        input = input.replace('c', 'p');
        input = input.replace('d', 'q');
        input = input.replace('e', 'r');
        input = input.replace('f', 's');
        input = input.replace('g', 't');
        input = input.replace('h', 'u');
        input = input.replace('i', 'v');
        input = input.replace('j', 'w');
        input = input.replace('k', 'x');
        input = input.replace('l', 'y');
        input = input.replace('m', 'z');
        input = input.replace('n', 'a');
        input = input.replace('o', 'b');
        input = input.replace('p', 'c');
        input = input.replace('q', 'd');
        input = input.replace('r', 'e');
        input = input.replace('s', 'f');
        input = input.replace('t', 'g');
        input = input.replace('u', 'h');
        input = input.replace('v', 'i');
        input = input.replace('w', 'j');
        input = input.replace('x', 'k');
        input = input.replace('y', 'l');
        input = input.replace('z', 'm');

        System.out.println("After replace: " + input);
    }
}
```

Comment: I would create a `Map<String, String>` for look-up, and a mask for ignoring keys.

Comment: The issue is `input = input.replace('u', 'h');` happens **after** `input = input.replace('h', 'u');` and changes it back to an `h`.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use some type of data structure to store the transpositions.

1. You could map every character. This way you will not replace any already-replaced-replacements.
2. Also, a mask can also be used to quickly toggle letters to be ignored.
3. Lastly, you could read the encryption key in as a text file and build the map dynamically.

This looks like a Caesar cipher, you could just shift the characters using a known algorithm.

```java
import java.util.*;

public class Encryption {
    static final Map<Character, Character> mapping;
    static final Set<Character> mask;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("Input a word: ");
        Scanner inputscan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("After replace: " + encrypt(inputscan.nextLine()));
        inputscan.close();
    }

    private static String encrypt(String plaintext) {
        StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer();
        for (char ch : plaintext.toCharArray()) {
            buff.append(!mask.contains(ch) && mapping.containsKey(ch)
                    ? mapping.get(ch)
                    : ch);
        }
        return buff.toString();
    }

    static {
        mapping = new HashMap<Character, Character>();
        mask = new HashSet<Character>();

        mapping.put('A', 'N');
        mapping.put('B', 'O');
        mapping.put('C', 'P');
        mapping.put('D', 'Q');
        mapping.put('E', 'R');
        mapping.put('F', 'S');
        mapping.put('G', 'T');
        mapping.put('H', 'U');
        mapping.put('I', 'V');
        mapping.put('J', 'W');
        mapping.put('K', 'X');
        mapping.put('L', 'Y');
        mapping.put('M', 'Z');
        mapping.put('N', 'A');
        mapping.put('O', 'B');
        mapping.put('P', 'C');
        mapping.put('Q', 'D');
        mapping.put('R', 'E');
        mapping.put('S', 'F');
        mapping.put('T', 'G');
        mapping.put('U', 'H');
        mapping.put('V', 'I');
        mapping.put('W', 'J');
        mapping.put('X', 'K');
        mapping.put('Y', 'L');
        mapping.put('Z', 'M');
        mapping.put('a', 'n');
        mapping.put('b', 'o');
        mapping.put('c', 'p');
        mapping.put('d', 'q');
        mapping.put('e', 'r');
        mapping.put('f', 's');
        mapping.put('g', 't');
        mapping.put('h', 'u');
        mapping.put('i', 'v');
        mapping.put('j', 'w');
        mapping.put('k', 'x');
        mapping.put('l', 'y');
        mapping.put('m', 'z');
        mapping.put('n', 'a');
        mapping.put('o', 'b');
        mapping.put('p', 'c');
        mapping.put('q', 'd');
        mapping.put('r', 'e');
        mapping.put('s', 'f');
        mapping.put('t', 'g');
        mapping.put('u', 'h');
        mapping.put('v', 'i');
        mapping.put('w', 'j');
        mapping.put('x', 'k');
        mapping.put('y', 'l');
        mapping.put('z', 'm');

        mask.add('a');
        mask.add('h');
    }
}
```

---

Here is an implementation of a Caesar cipher (adapted from [this Ruby example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34278160/1762224)).

```java
import java.util.*;

public class EncryptionUtil {
    private static final Set<Character> MASK;

    static {
        MASK = new HashSet<Character>(Arrays.asList('a', 'h'));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String phrase = "action >> hello world";
        System.out.println(phrase);

        String encrypted = caesarCipher(phrase, 13, MASK);
        System.out.println(encrypted);

        String plaintext = caesarCipher(encrypted, 13, MASK);
        System.out.println(plaintext);
    }

    private static String caesarCipher(String plaintext, int shift, Set<Character> mask) {
        StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer();
        for (char ch : plaintext.toCharArray()) {
            if (!mask.contains(ch) && Character.isAlphabetic(ch)) {
                int baseOrd = (int) (ch >= 'a' ? 'a' : 'A');
                int origPos = ((int) ch) - baseOrd;
                int newPos = (origPos + shift) % 26;
                buff.append((char) (baseOrd + newPos));
            } else {
                buff.append(ch);
            }
        }
        return buff.toString();
    }

    private static String caesarCipher(String plaintext, int shift) {
        return caesarCipher(plaintext, shift, Collections.<Character>emptySet());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
action >> hello world
apgvba >> hryyb jbeyq
actioa >> hello world
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code you are replacing letters multiple times. Here is my solution is to use a loop and replace letters one by one:

```
public class HelloWorld {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.print("Input a word: ");
    Scanner inputscan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = inputscan.nextLine();

    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(input);
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {

        switch (input.charAt(i)) {
            case 'A':
                stringBuilder.setCharAt(i, 'N');
                break;
            case 'B':
                stringBuilder.setCharAt(i, 'O');
                break;

            //Add all the other cases here.

        }
    }
    System.out.println("After replace: " + stringBuilder.toString());
}

}
```